# Post SQLi results ($var->fetch_object) on a for cycle

Tags: php, string, mysqli

I have this php script which posts results from the database on a html form:

```
$link = new mysqli($host, $u, $pw, $db);
$link->query("...")
...
while($result = $fromdb->fetch_object()){
   ...
   for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
      ...
      print '<div>
             <label class="energytypes" for="something'.$i.'">Something:</label>                  
             <input type="text
                    ...
                    value="'.$result->{something.$i}.'">
              </div>';
   }
}
```

Is this:

```
$result->{something.$i}
```

the only and/or correct way to get:

```
$result->something1
$result->something2
$result->something3
```

Thank you

**EDIT**

After suggestions I decided to use mysqli_fetch_array.

The complete (working) code is:

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($fromdb)){
   ...
   for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
      ...
      print '<div>
             <label class="energytypes" for="something'.$i.'">Something:</label>                  
             <input type="text
                    ...
                    value="'.$result['something'.$i].'">
              </div>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered fetching an array instead of an object? Seems like it better suits your needs in this scenario.

Comment: Edited with array. So I'll use this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's the correct way. (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

You could of course fetch an associative array instead, if that would feel more intuitive. But other than that, this is the PHP way of accessing properties with variable names.

Comment: I edited the original post with the array. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i meant!

Comment: I'm not sure if you are selecting anymore data than your something1 - something9 but maybe $result = mysqli_fetch_array($fromdb, MYSQLI_NUM); might be cleaner.

Comment: Yes I select other data. So it's clearer without MYSQLI_NUM. Thank you for the suggestion!